# R: Date discrepancy when creating a dataframe with a date variable

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I'm trying to create dataframe in R with a date column that is populated from a pre-defined variable. When I do this the date is changed to a seemingly random future date. Here is what I have:

```
DateVar <- as.Date("2/6/2020", format = "%m/%d/%Y")
Size <- 50

Results <- data.frame(COMP_NAM=character(Size),
                      COMM_DTE=as.Date(Size, origin = DateVar),
                      ID=character(Size),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then when I look at the dataframe, column COMM_DTE is populated with "2020-04-29". But when I print `DateVar` R returns "2020-02-06".

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Are you converting `50` to `COMM_DTE`.   I guess you need `DateVar` which is already in `Date` class

Comment: What are you trying to do with `COMM_DTE=as.Date(Size, origin = DateVar)`, create a date that's 50 days after `DateVar`? I think you're safer with something like `DateVar + Size`, which will add 50 (days) to that date. Although I get the same date (2020-03-27) with `as.Date(Size, origin = DateVar)` as with `DateVar + Size`, so I'm not sure how you're getting 4/29

Comment: I think you are correct. When I change `Size`, it returns a different date. My understanding was that the first argument pertained to the number of rows

Comment: Forgot tags for notifications @akrun

Comment: @camille I'm trying to return the same date, so that (2020-02-06) is the value for all rows in COMM_DTE for the dataframe

Comment: No, the first argument of `as.Date` is the string you're trying to convert to a date. In this case, you're trying to convert the number 50 to a date. Either way, I'm unsure where you're getting 4/29 from

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but based on your last comment do you just want `COMM_DTE=DateVar` when creating your data.frame? That will give you the same value for `COMM_DTE` throughout your entire data.frame (all 50 rows). If I'm off let me know.

Comment: @Ben That's correct!